# Logs Generated when launching an App in Kivy Launcher on Android

Tags: python, logging, kivy

I know we can launch an app in Android using Kivy launcher for android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.pygame

and i can launch apps by the same as well . But i need to know how and where can we see the logs generated by the app in it ? For example if i run kivy app on my desktop i will  be able to see logs on console but where will i find them when launching an app by kivy launcher ?

If we cant see logs is there any ways to make this possible  ?

Answer (score 3):

On android, kivy prints all python's normal terminal output to the android logcat stream. You can view this from the desktop by connecting your phone via usb and doing `adb logcat`. adb is provided by the android sdk, so if it's not in your path you can probably find it there. If you use `buildozer`, I think you can access its auto-downloaded android sdk using

> buildozer android logcat

You can also view the adb output using some apps on the play store (may only work with older android versions though, I think something changed here).

Kivy may also store logs as text files somewhere on the sd card, possibly in the app directory (i.e. somewhere in the kivy launcher's `kivy` directory), but I haven't ever really used this, adb is a lot more convenient.

Comment: kivy usually saves the logs in the kivy launcher project directory as .kivy but those logs are just kivy logs . I mean it dont show any of the outputs of the print statements .

Answer (score 1):

When your application is executed a .kivy folder will be created (if not already there).
In it you'll see a logs folder. The logs there are the same obtained via "adb logcat".

Answer (score 0):

You should specify package name in `buildozer.spec` file like below

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = MyApp

# (str) Package name
package.name = MyAppication

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = ir.MyApp

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY , NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

# (str) Android entry point , default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
```

Then with command below you can

```bash
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb logcat ir.MyApp:D MyApp:D ir.MyApp.MyAppication:D *:S MyAppication:D org.kivy.android.PythonActivity:D org.kivy:D python:D
```

Note that what ever you call `entrypoint` and `package` you should use them to filter your logs

[I should mention](https://developer.android.com/tools/logcat#filteringOutput) that `D` after packages name is stand for `Debug`

- `V`: Verbose (lowest priority)
- `D`: Debug
- `I`: Info
- `W`: Warning
- `E`: Error
- `F`: Fatal
- `S`: Silent (highest priority, where nothing is ever printed)

Also If you want clear old logs you can use `adb logcat -c`