# android permissions in python using request_permissions

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create an android app that sends messages, but I can't get permission to do that.
I am using request_permissions to get permission but nothing appears.
I am sending a message with `androidhelper_r6` and I will get:

> AttributeError: 'Android' object has no attribute '_rpc'.

I don't know if it's because of no permission or to something else.

Python code:

```
class DemoApplicationApp(MDApp):

def build(self):
    self.screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
    request_permissions([Permission.SEND_SMS, Permission.INTERNET])
    return self.screen

def send_message(self):
    droid = android.Android()
    droid.smsSend("420xxxxxxxxx", "Message")
    
DemoApplicationApp().run()
```

`buildozer.spec`:

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = Demo

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,pythonforandroid,jnius

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET,SEND_SMS,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 29

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Log from Android Studio:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity" -a 

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.5.13401 Core Profile Context 
15.201.1301.0)'>

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google (ATI Technologies Inc.)'>

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (AMD 
Radeon HD 6470M)'>

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <18>

I/python: [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider

I/python: [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

I/python: [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

I/python: [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available

V/PythonActivity: addPermissionsCallback(): Added callback for onRequestPermissionsResult

V/PythonActivity: onPause()

V/SDL: onPause()
nativePause()

V/SDL: onWindowFocusChanged(): false

I/python: [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider

I/python: [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop

V/PythonActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult()

onRequestPermissionsResult passed to callback

V/PythonActivity: onResume()

V/SDL: onResume()

V/SDL: onWindowFocusChanged(): true

nativeResume()

I/python: [WARNING] [Base        ] Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android 
presplash.

I/python: [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python:    File "/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", 
line 130, in <module>
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1402, in on_motion
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1418, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1191, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1191, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivymd/uix/behaviors/ripplebehavior.py", line 231, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivymd/uix/button.py", line 961, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi- 
v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
I/python:    File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
I/python:    File "/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", 
line 118, in send_message
I/python:    File 
"/home/subsystem/environments/MobileMsgSender_Copy/.buildozer/android/app/androidhelper_r6.py", line 
2071, in smsSend
I/python:  AttributeError: 'Android' object has no attribute '_rpc'
    Python for android ended
```

Comment: What is android.Android? Is it a supported method? Post a full example

Comment: You also need the `android.permissions` in your `buildozer.spec` (and uncommented).

Comment: To the first comment: import androidhelper_r6 as android,  [link to androidhelper_r6]: https://github.com/brousch/sl4a_pydroid_mock_api/tree/master/src/android I am using it like androidhelper [link]: https://kylelk.github.io/html-examples/androidhelper.html

Comment: Update: I imported permissions.py as you wrote  `from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission` .If I request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it works, but if I request `SEND_SMS` it doesn't work. I also have `SEND_SMS` in my `buildozer.spec` I think it's something with `permissions groups` but I don't know how to create new permission group. I have got only permission group named storage with storage permissions. Thank's for help

Comment: I created another question to this for people which have got same problem like this [link]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431669/permissions-groups-in-android-with-python

Answer (score 1):

The 'request_permissions' line is missing a callback method after the list of permissions

You can checkout this video where function is used https://youtu.be/okpiDnSR4z8 TimeStamp:(28:25)

Or you can checkout this github post https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1004

Comment: While these links can contain information needed to solve this question, it is always good to add all necessary info into the answer itself, such as example code and explanation. That would increase quality of your answer and possily lead to more up-votes.