# Why the error Cython is not installed while using buildozer?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

After managing all configuration in the spec file generated by buildozer and running the final command `buildozer -v android debug` I am getting the following error.

```
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
/bin/sh: dpkg: command not found
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
# Cython (cython) not found, please install it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you can try :

```
sudo apt-get install cython
pip3 install Cython
```

// refer to my own [ans post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533163/14946345)

Comment: trying pip3 install Cython shows requirement already satisfied

Comment: then have you tried using apt ?  and could you post full log ( make the log level in `buildozer.spec` = 2 ) ? thx